# Why does NSString sizeWithFont: return the wrong size?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextview

I need to work out the height of a UITextView from the top down to the cursor. I am trimming the text it contains (so it only goes up to the cursor) and then using NSString's `sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:` method to work out the height, like so:

```
   NSRange range;
   range.location = noteTextView.selectedRange.location;
   range.length = noteTextView.text.length - range.location;

   NSString *string = [noteTextView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:@""];

   CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:noteTextView.font 
                     constrainedToSize:noteTextView.frame.size 
                         lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

   NSLog(@"height is: %f \n", size.height);
```

It does this every time I type anything.

The problem is, when I watch the NSLog as I type, it doesn't register a change of height until I have typed 4 characters on the new line. It is as if the `sizeWithFont` method is exactly four characters out. Here's a couple of screenshots showing what I mean:
[image: Height with three characters on line]
[image: Height with four characters on line]

Can anyone tell me what is going on?

Comment: problem probably is that text view has margins on sides when displays text, so its actual width is less then textview's frame width

Comment: @Vladimir - Why was that a comment instead of an answer? I think you're absolutely right but can't vote it as a good answer :)

Comment: You make a lot of assumptions that UITextView renders exactly as your calculations are done... It might work or might not, now or in the future. @Vladimir has pointed out the problem here, I guess.

Comment: @deanWombourne because I was not 100% sure it was correct and didn't have solution for that anyway

Comment: @Vladimir deanWombourne found the solution but your answer was very helpful - please put it as an answer so I can at least up-vote you :)

Comment: @RicLevy. np :) may be I'll have an answer for your next questions and you'll upvote then

Answer (score 6, accepted):

@Vladimir's comment is right I think - an NSString doesn't take into account the margins of a UITextField.

You could try getting the text preceding the cursor and creating a new UITextField that only contains that text.

Then if you call `[tempTextField sizeToFit]` on your new text field then it's bounds should be the size you are looking for.

Comment: I just saw Vladimir's comment and I tried calculating the textView's `contentInset` and subtracting it from the width. This is much better, but not perfect (only one character out now). I suspect that, as Eiko suggests, I can never be 100% sure that I know exactly how UITextView will render, so I guess your method is the only way I can be sure of accuracy...

Comment: Ah - one problem: I'm using a UITextView, not a UITextField, so there's no sizeToFit method. Hopefully there's a way round it, though... I'll report back if I find it.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. I've set up a tempTextField, and it's going through all the same code that makes it expand as the text string gets longer, but it's height always shows as being the same! I'm guessing that's because it hasn't actually been added to the view. But I can't add it to the view overlapping the 'real' textView, because that makes the app crash. :(

Comment: sizeToFit is a method on UIView so it should always exist! And you can add it to the view fine, just set the alpha to 0.001 so it can't be seen - a crash means you're adding it wrong (probably to do with memory retain/release) ;) - post your adding code to the question and we'll take a look.