# How can I work out the margin size of a UITextView?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, nsstring, uitextview

I am trying to work out the size of a size of a textView up to the cursor by trimming all the text after the cursor, and then using NSString's `sizeWithFont` method, like so:

```
    NSString *string = [myTextView.text substringToIndex:myTextView.selectedRange.location];        
    CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:myTextView.font constrainedToSize:myTextView.frame.size lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Unfortunately, this never returns quite the right size, probably because the text has margins, so its actual width is less than UITextView's width (thanks to the answerers of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5990650/why-does-nsstring-sizewithfont-return-the-wrong-size) for working that out).

So I need to work out the size of the margins, and subtract that from the UITextView's size to get the actual size of the text area. Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like the answer is that there is no margin in UITextView - you just have to simulate one by putting a view behind it, and making the UITextView narrower. If you need the background to scroll with the text, you can listen for `scrollViewDidScroll:`.

Comment: For scrollview indicator issue, this answer might help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343390/is-there-a-way-to-put-uitextviews-scroll-indicator-to-outside-uitextview

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest

```
CGSize tSize = myTextView.frame.size;
tSize.width -= 2 * myTextView.contentInset.left;
tSize.height -= 2 * myTextView.contentInset.top;
CGSize size = [string sizeWithFont:myTextView.font constrainedToSize:tSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
```

Comment: I'm not at my computer but I'm pretty sure I tried removing contentInset without success - and then worked out using NSLogs that contentInset values were zero. It seems like they are using something else to create the margins. I'll verify and report back, though.

Comment: Yep, confirm I'm afraid - the contentInset values for a UITextView are zero.